# Xcode 6: Create init function automatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Is there a way in Xcode 6 to generate the init function automatically?

An example for better understanding:

I have these properties:

```
var name: String
var location: String
var date : NSDate
var host: String
var description: String
```

and I want to generate this init function automatically:

```
    init (name: String, location: String, date: NSDate, host: String, description: String, eventReceived: NSDate) {
        self.name = name;
        self.location = location
        self.date = date
        self.host = host
        self.description = description
    }
```

Comment: search for how to make code templates

Comment: Use TextWrangler (or another editor) and regex to mangle the vars to an init.

Answer (score 6):

You can use GenerateSwiftInit extension for Xcode 8 - Proof of concept for Xcode 8 source extensions; generate a Swift init from current selection

Comment: A developer-signed mac app is included in the GenerateSwiftInit directory. It is compatible with macOS 10.12 and Xcode 8. You need to download and move it to your /Applications directory, then Open System Preferences > Extensions to Ensure the checkbox for GenerateSwiftInit is checked. Restart Xcode and enjoy it

Comment: Although I downloaded GenerateSwiftInt and put it into my /Applications folder, I don't see GenerateSwiftInit in the extensions in System Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Not for classes, but for structs you will automatically get a memberwise initializer like the one you are looking for: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_319)